# Returned Pomises not called/triggered when trying to update & delete multiple locations angular firebase web api

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

Trying to set up multiple deletions of locatins when deleting a post.

But **Problem** the method does not continue past the following line of code:
`const deleteFromDatabase = this.db.ref().update(updateObject);`

Drawing a blank on how to implement this logic. How can I get this to following though beyon that line of code. For example when there are storageUri's (picture and thumb) it doesn't seem to reach the if conditional to return Promise.all

```
deletePost(postId, pictureStorageUri, thumbStorageUri): Promise<any> {
        console.log(`Deleting ${postId}`);

        // CONSTRUCT/DEFINE update object for real-time database data deletion
        const updateObject = {};
        updateObject[`/posts/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/people/${this.currentUser.uid}/posts/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/feed/${this.currentUser.uid}/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/comments/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/likes/${postId}`] = null;

        // DEFINE/CALL deleteFromDatabase promise
        const deleteFromDatabase = this.db.ref().update(updateObject);

        // IF Picture Uris DEFINE/CALL storage delete promises
        if (pictureStorageUri) {
            const deleteFullFromStorage = this.storage.refFromURL(pictureStorageUri).delete();
            const deleteThumbFromStorage = this.storage.refFromURL.delete();
            console.log('promise being called');
            return Promise.all([deleteFromDatabase, deleteFullFromStorage, deleteThumbFromStorage]);
        }

        // RETURNS this promise if no picture uris
        return deleteFromDatabase;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return something from the if statement your code needs to look something like this:

```
deletePost(postId, pictureStorageUri, thumbStorageUri): Promise<any> {
        console.log(`Deleting ${postId}`);

        // CONSTRUCT/DEFINE update object for real-time database data deletion
        const updateObject = {};
        updateObject[`/posts/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/people/${this.currentUser.uid}/posts/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/feed/${this.currentUser.uid}/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/comments/${postId}`] = null;
        updateObject[`/likes/${postId}`] = null;

        // DEFINE/CALL deleteFromDatabase promise
        let promise = this.db.ref().update(updateObject);

        // IF Picture Uris DEFINE/CALL storage delete promises
        if (pictureStorageUri) {
            const deleteFullFromStorage = this.storage.refFromURL(pictureStorageUri).delete();
            const deleteThumbFromStorage = this.storage.refFromURL.delete();
            console.log('promise being called');
            promise = Promise.all([promise, deleteFullFromStorage, deleteThumbFromStorage]);
        }

        // RETURNS this promise if no picture uris
        return promise;
    }
```

Just to give you an idea, maybe you can use another helper variable to make the naming more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but end up being that the promisor does not return a message(I thought the firebase api even with promise.all would return 1 but it does notcompared to if you are only using the update method alone) when resolving it and the other part of the application, essentially returns either success, failure & you can catch it 1 resolving it

Answer (score 0):

End up being that the promise.all does not return a success message(I thought the firebase api even with promise.all would return 1 but it does not compared to if you are only using the .update() method alone) when resolving it and the other part of the application, essentially returns either success, failure & you can catch it 1 resolving it. Which allows you to confirm that it is done.

I confirmed that all was deleted in the real-time database & looked at sample code from another source